# Java Script 連想配列の変更について

Tags: javascript

Java Script 連想配列の変更について

```
Array(
　　{ id : 1, name : 'aaaa' },
　　{ id : 2, name : 'bbbb' }
)
```

を以下の通りに変換したい

```
Array(
　　id : Array( 1 ,2 ),
　　name : Array( 'aaaa' ,'bbbb' )
)
```

Comment: 欲しい結果の意図が不明です。[ { id:[...]}, { name:[... ]} ]、{ id:[...], name:[...] }、[{ id:[...], name:[...] }] のどれかでしょうか? あと、不完全でもいいので自身で書いたコードを添えると回答しやすいです。

Comment: どういったルールでの変換を意図しているのか、言葉による説明もあると親切で誤解なく伝わりやすくなると思います。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて質問文を見直してみてください。